# On-premise TFS 2015 web site: Missing TFS "Process"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is it possible in TFS 2015 on-premise to modify a collections process templates? According to the article here, there should be a "process" tab on the web interface, collection administration page.  This document is for 2015 but is a little old.  Should this feature be available for 2015 on-premise upgrade 2?  Am I missing a permission?

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/customize/customize-work#team-projects-and-processes-team-services-

Answer (score 3):

Just as the article mentioned, the settings are with VS Team Service. *Team projects and processes (**Team Services**)* And there is **no “process” tab on the web interface for TFS2015.**

[image]

Scroll down the page and you will see *Team projects and process templates (**TFS**)*

> When you **work with an on-premises TFS**, you customize your work
>   tracking experience **through one or more XML definition files.** You can
>   start by customizing a process template and its XML definition files,
>   and then create a team project based on the template. Or, you can
>   simply make modifications as needed to add customizations to the work
>   item fields, work item types, and other objects that support tracking
>   work.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer, but it was unclear to me if it was VSTS only. Also given some VSTS functionality is pushed to on-prem through regular updates, I hoped I was missing something.

Comment: I have also checked my TFS update 2 and the release notes of it.  I'm sure there is no such updates.   Below is the release note link:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Comment: Moreover, although some VSTS functionality will be pushed to on-prem through regular updates. But, there are also some features only available from the cloud service or from an on-premises deployment.